# integration testing rabbitmq consumer

Tags: python, unit-testing, rabbitmq

I have a simple consumer written in python using pika and rabbitmq.

The consumer connects to rabbitmq and listens on a queue. When a message arrives it transforms the message and publishes it on another queue.

Presented here: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/fbanke/8e7zbX

I would like to make test cases to test the interaction between the consumer and the queue. For example, I would like to make sure that when a message is consumed the "basic_ack" function is called to let rabbitmq know that the message was processed.

Another test case is if the consumer reconnects to rabbitmq if the connection gets dropped.

And so on. I want to test the interaction between the consumer and the queue not the actual business logic in the consumer.

If I mock the pika objects it requires me to understand 100% how the API behaves and any misunderstanding of the API will result in faulty code. Code that passes the tests, but actually doesn't work.

I would rather test the consumer using a live queue, and manipulate it from the test to see if the consumer behaves as expected.

For example
1. setup the queue
2. start the consumer
3. publish a valid message to the queue
4. assert that the message was consumed by the worker

or

1. setup the queue
2. start the consumer
3. kill the queue
4. assert that the worker terminated as expected

Does there exist any best-practice on how to do this? I can find many examples of similar tests on databases, but not for queues. It seems that I need to start the consumer in a separate thread and work with it, but it seems that there is no infrastructure to support this.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?